# Counting occurrences

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a code that will count the number of occurrences of 1 string in another string. So for if the user enters "hello" and then enter "e" the code should say "There is 1 occurrence of "e". However, my current executes an infinite loop.

I've tried changing the condition on the for loop to `inputEntry.equals(inputCharacter)` but also had an infinite loop.

```
package charcounter;

import java.util.Scanner;
public class CharCounter {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        String inputEntry;
        String inputCharacter;

        System.out.println("Please enter a multi word string: ");
        inputEntry = scnr.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter another string: ");
        inputCharacter = scnr.nextLine();

        if (inputCharacter.length() == 1){
            while (inputEntry.contains(inputCharacter)){
                int occurrences = 0;
                for(occurrences = 0;inputEntry.contains(inputCharacter); occurrences++ ){
                    System.out.println("There is " + occurrences + " of " + inputCharacter);
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Your string is too long.");
        }
    }
}
```

So for if the user enters "hello" and then enter "e" the code should say "There is 1 occurrence of "e".

Comment: When did you expect the loop to end? Why?

Comment: Your program is saying "while the inputEntry contains inputCharacter keep looping". How do you expect this not to be an infinite loop? Both the `while` and the `for` loops will never end.

Comment: I wanted the loop to end once it was done counting the number of occurrences. So if the word was "Good" and the second string entered was "g" the loop would read the word good and see g came up only once and then stop and report 1 occurrence.

Comment: I'm new to Java so I'm trying to go through all the resources I have available to me and what I was taught up until now.

Comment: Yes, but `contains` checks the whole string. Read the Javadoc! https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains-java.lang.CharSequence-

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/5221149)

Answer (score 0):

The `inputEntry.contains(inputCharacter)` in your code always return true => endless loop

You can change to indexOf for your requirement.

```
int lastIndex = 0;
int count = 0;

while(lastIndex != -1){

    lastIndex = inputEntry.indexOf(inputCharacter,lastIndex);

    if(lastIndex != -1){
        count ++;
        lastIndex += inputCharacter.length();
    }
}
```

You can change your code to

```
 if (inputCharacter.length() == 1){
      int lastIndex = 0;
      int count = 0;

      while(lastIndex != -1){

        lastIndex = inputEntry.indexOf(inputCharacter,lastIndex);

        if(lastIndex != -1){
            count ++;
            lastIndex += inputCharacter.length();
        }
       }
       System.out.println("There is " + count + " of " + inputCharacter);
   }
   else{
            System.out.println("Your string is too long.");
   }
```

Comment: Incorrect call to [`indexOf(String str, int fromIndex)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-java.lang.String-int-)

Comment: What is `str`??

Comment: Thanks for assist but we haven't been taught indexof in our class yet. Is there any way to use the structure I have? Plus if I were to add a print out statement likeSystem.out.println("There is " + count + " of " + inputCharacter); it would print corrrently for 1 character but for more than one occurence it would print out as there is 1 of 2.